# Considering the testing software issues when designing software

Tags: design, database, testing

When designing the software, must we consider how much this code could be testable? for example, if we used X technology/Class/Interface instead of Y, based on that X can be tested more easily than Y, Is that a good design?

**Use Case:** I faced a problem when writing the integration test of our software which was built upon Spring Boot technology, we plan to test the database operations by inserting the testing data to the database and test the software based on them, the issues was that we cannot change the data in that database, so each transaction must be rolled back, and the `JpaRepository` cannot read the uncommitted transactions, so the solution was `JpaDialect`. Assuming that there are no "obvious" drawbacks can arise from using `JpaDialect`.

How much this will be correct if we adopt `JpaDialect` rather than `JpaRespository` because the former is easier to test than the latter?

Comment: The answer is obviously "yes", testability "must be considered" (I prefer to say "it is a good idea to consider it"). So do you have a specific question to ask (something which is not tool specific like this Jpa stuff, since tool recommendations are explicitl off-topic on this site)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The testability of a system is something that should be considered during architecture and design, but it's only one aspect of the system. You'll also likely be considering performance, security, usability (from the perspective of both users and developers), availability, and other quality attributes.

When you're designing your software, you should put some level of effort into making it easy to control and observe the state of the system and to limit the complexity. Both of these lead to more testable systems. However, you need to balance testability with the other attributes of the system.

I don't think anyone here can tell you if you should use `JpaDialect` or `JpaRepository` without a much deeper understanding of your system and objectives. It's a very subjective call to say which design is better without constraining your solutions. But it's something that you should be considering and the development team should be talking about.

Comment: I just add the JPA examples to make my question clear. I'm not asking about which to use at all

Comment: @hbak Then my first two paragraphs answer your question.